# How to draw outside borders only in thead

Tags: html, css

Here is a jsfiddle of my html/css: http://jsfiddle.net/S8Bne/49/

In the the top header, as you can see, there are solid black borders around each th.

I only want to draw a border around the outside of the th group.  How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way using `:first-child` and `:last-child` pseudo selectors

```
.geniusPicks table tr#picksHeading th {background:darkRed; color:white; font-weight:bold; border-top:solid 1px #000; border-bottom:solid 1px #000;}
.geniusPicks table tr#picksHeading th:first-child {border-left:solid 1px #000;}
.geniusPicks table tr#picksHeading th:last-child {border-right:solid 1px #000;}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/S8Bne/52/)

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the line: `.geniusPicks table tr#picksHeading th`, specifically with the style `{ border:1px solid #000; }` which makes a border for all four sides. To set a border on top and bottom, but not left and right, you need to specifiy each border individually using its longhand version: `border-*position*`

Update your code as follows:

```
.geniusPicks table tr#picksHeading th { 
   background:darkRed;
   color:white;
   font-weight:bold;
   /* replace border:1px solid #000 with these four rules */
   border-top:1px solid #000;
   border-bottom:1px solid #000; 
   border-left:none; 
   border-right:none;
}
```